# How to redirect back to the page after redirect from that page to login with flask login manager with custom login.html

Tags: redirect, flask-login

So i made a login form:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('login', next=request.endpoint) }}" method="post" class="card-body cardbody-color p-lg-5">
  <div class="mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="login" required>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success px-5 mb-5 w-100">log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

key point is:

```html
action="{{ url_for('login', next=request.endpoint) }}"
```

Thats my login backend:

```
@server.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    username = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    next_page = request.args.get('next')

    if not next_page:
        next_page = '/'

    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash('You are already logged in!')
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    if username and password:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if not user:
            flash('incorrect login')
            return render_template('flask_user/login.html')
        if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect(next_page)
        else:
            flash('incorrect password')
    else:
        flash('Enter login and password')
    return render_template('flask_user/login.html')
```

That's my redirect handler:

```
@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def redirect_to_signin(response):
    return redirect(url_for('login'), next=request.endpoint)
```

Login manager works perfectly:

> http://10.104.4.95:8080/login?next=/arm_analyst

But after i am pressing the log in button, it refreshes the page, so request.endpoint become "login".

I could see only 2 ways of solving this:

1. to force "next" argument not to change after pressing the log in button
2. to send from without refreshing

But both looks strange to me because i suppose there is another way to do that.

could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the url inside form action, can you set `action=""` instead of `action="{{ url_for('login', next=request.endpoint) }}"`